# Prove Zn=min{Sn,4} where Sn=X1+...+Xn is markov chain by definition

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Xn  are i.i.d random variables with P[Xn=1]=P[Xn=0]=1/2 and we we also have Sn=X1+...+Xn. Show that Zn=min{Sn,4} is a Markov Chain and find it transition matrix.

I know that Sn=Sn−1+Xn but I don't see how to use it in conditioning to make variables independent.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(Z_n)_n$ is a Markov chain, because the distribution of $Z_{n+1}$ is determined by the distribution of $Z_n$ only, and it does not depend on the distribution of $Z_{i}, i \le n-1$. In general, independence is irrelevant for Markov chains.

Let $p(\cdot,\cdot)$ be the transition probability for $(Z_n)_n$.
Since $Z_n \le 4$, we need to consider $p(x,y)$ only for $x, y \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Since $S_n$ is non-decreasing, if $Z_n = 4$, then, $Z_{n+1} = 4$.
Hence, $p(4,i) = \begin{cases} 1 \ \ \ i = 4 \\  0 \ \ \ i \ne 4 \end{cases}$.

If $Z_n = 3$, then, $S_n = 3$ and hence $Z_{n+1} = S_{n+1}= 4$ iff $X_{n+1} = 1$ and $Z_{n+1} = S_{n+1} = 3$ iff $X_{n+1} = 0$.
Hence, $p(3,i) = \begin{cases} 1/2 \ \ \ i = 4 \\  1/2 \ \ \ i = 3 \end{cases}$.

In the same manner,
$p(2,i) = \begin{cases} 1/2 \ \ \ i = 3 \\  1/2 \ \ \ i = 2 \end{cases}$,
$p(1,i) = \begin{cases} 1/2 \ \ \ i = 2 \\  1/2 \ \ \ i = 1 \end{cases}$, and,
$p(0,i) = \begin{cases} 1/2 \ \ \ i = 1 \\  1/2 \ \ \ i = 0 \end{cases}$.

So, the transition matrix $P = (p(x,y))_{x,y = 0,1,2,3,4}$ is given by $$ P = \begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$